# TS video file format no audio with a VideoView

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, android-videoview

I am trying to play .ts video format into `videoview` and it plays like charm but there is no audio sound on it, I am getting the video URL from my JSON file and I tried to enable audio with Java code like this

```
videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.setVolume(1, 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Does the ts file contain a supported audio codec?

Comment: @szatmary i don't know, how am i suppose to check that?